# Can't connect to Mosquitto server using paho.mqtt.client although mosquitto_pub works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have a remote server running mosquitto. I can connect to this server and exchange messages using mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub. If i try the same using some python with paho.mqtt.client I get no connection. My script keeps running but the on_connection hook is never called.. The same scripts however work flawlessly with my local mosquitto server.

What could possibly be the reason for the connection problems? How can I get some more feedback on what's happening? Any suggestions?

EDIT: I added a minimal code example

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Yeeha")
    client.subscribe("botgrid/init", qos=2)

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.payload)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("localhost")
print("Waiting for connection...")
client.loop_forever()
```

EDIT 2: While playing around, I noted that replacing "localhost" with "test.mosquitto.org" resulted in `OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable` although I have no problems connecting to it via mosquitto_sub

Comment: Can you post your (or a section of) script so we can have a look?

Comment: What version of mosquitto? I bet you're on 0.15 or 1.2.x.

Comment: @ralight I just now installed mosquitto version 1.3.5 (build date 2014-10-08 22:31:34+0000) in hope that this solved the issue. However, it didn't.

Comment: That code snippet works fine for me with localhost, a broker on my local net and test.mosquitto.org. My only thought about the Network unreachable error is that it's reachable via IPv6 and you only have IPv4. Have you tried using IP addresses instead of names?

Comment: Yes, I have. Again, 127.0.0.1 results in a yeeha, the remote IP does not. Is there any way I can get more information out of the client that helps me closing in on the cause?

Comment: I can't see any trace in the python code, best suggestion at this point is use something like wireshark to capture all the traffic on port 1883

Comment: Thank you for your time spent!I was hoping to avoid that, but if all else fails...

Comment: Just use `mosquitto -v` to see verbose info. If `Sending CONNACK to ...` is displayed, then the client maybe not receiving traffic data (something wrong with the `client.loopforever()`), or the server is not running properly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code produce the same problem? This is probably the equivalent to the code at the point that it is failing.

```
import socket

sock = socket.create_connection(("test.mosquitto.org", 1883))
```

Comment: so did you test it?